# Searching in object inside array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, authentication

I'm trying to hardcode a kind of log in system, for that i was trying to have two inputs and on click check if those values matched the ones in the array, the array having two objects for two possible answers…

Well, i cant get it to work, all of the suden my variables are not recognized and the overall code has gone kaput… here is the [Pen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/MJMZMK)

thanks in advance!

the code so far btw

```
$(".submit").click(function() {

//bidimensional array
var data = [{
    user: "cinco",
    pw: "king"
}, {
    user: "manco",
    pw: "wawa"
}];
var name = $(".name").val();
var pass = $(".pw").val();

if (data.user.includes(name) && data.pw.includes(pass)) {
    $(".check-input").addClass('valid');
} else {
    $(".check-input").addClass('invalid');
  }
});

$(".input").focus(function() {
  $(".check-input").removeClass("valid");
  $(".check-input").removeClass("invalid");
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan seems like he already changed it to my code in the pen..

Comment: @baao - ach - missed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find()` like this

```
if (data.find(v => v.user === name && v.pw === pass)) { ... }
```

Please note that using javascript as your login is highly insecure as everybody can just open the console and read the credentials.

For your comment, the => is part of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), it boils down to

```
if (data.find(function(v) { 
    return v.user === name && v.pw === pass; 
})) { ... }
```

Comment: Just wanted to add the note :) @Miguel

Comment: just one thing, what is the "v =>" part doing?

Comment: Added the explanation to the answer  @Miguel

Comment: so, they are the same thing?

Comment: Not exactly the same, there are some differences. Better read the documentation pages we posted. But for this specific example, they do the same and behave equally, but the arrow function is shorter... @Miguel

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{
    user: "cinco",
    pw: "king"
}, {
    user: "manco",
    pw: "wawa"
}];

checkLogin(usr, pwd){
  for(var index in data) {
    var obj = data[index];
    if(obj.user == usr && obj.pw == pwd) {
     return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

checkLogin('chino', 'wrongPwd'); // returns false
checkLogin('chino', 'king'); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the individual objects in the array and get the `user` and `pw` properties of those objects. The array itself doesn't have those properties.

Here's a working version that also streamlines your code:

```js
$(".submit").click(function() {

 // This is not a bidimensional array. It's just an array of objects
 var data = [{
  user: "cinco",
  pw: "king"
 }, {
  user: "manco",
  pw: "wawa"
 }];
  
 var name = $(".name").val();
 var pass = $(".pw").val();

  // You need to access the individual objects in the array and get
  // the user and pw properties of those objects. The array itself
  // doesn't have those properties.
  
  // Loop through the array and check each object
  // You can't return from a forEach loop, so we'll set up a variable
  // that will be used after the loop is complete
  var valid = false;
  data.forEach(function(obj){
    // Don't check for inclusion of the data, check for exact match
   if (obj.user === name && obj.pw === pass) {
     valid = true;
   } 
  });
  
  // Now that the loop is done, set the validity
  $(".check-input").addClass(valid ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
 
});

$(".input").focus(function() {
 $(".check-input").removeClass("valid");
 $(".check-input").removeClass("invalid");
});
```

```css
.check-input{
 width:250px;
 height:40px;
 background-color:gray;

}
.valid{
 background-color:green;
}

.invalid{
 background-color:crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input name">
<input type="text" class="input pw">
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
<div class="check-input"></div>
```